# My PS3 Slim won't connect to any controller wirelessly!

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, controllers

So, I don't know if my problem is unique, but I need an answer to it. My PS3 Slim is not connecting to any of my DualShock 3 controllers wirelessly. And, no, they are not out of battery. I can use them fine on my brother's PS3 Super Slim, and they have full battery there.

I feel like my problem is being caused by my PS3 Slim itself. If anyone can help, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking other wireless accessories like a headset - if you have that possibility. If not, I don't see any other idea than take your PS3 to service, because the Bluetooth module may be broken.